# Can random writes to a non-formatted raw partition from linux corrupt the boot loader?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, io

**In brief**: suppose I create a non-formatted raw partition on my hard drive, and read and write block IOs to and from it using the standard c interface: open, pread, pwrite, etc. Is there any reason why doing this should corrupt my bootloader? I ask because my bootloaded was corrupted twice in 2 weeks, and I don't have any clue what's going on.

**Full story**: I am running a database-like application that writes and reads block IOs of size 8kb to and from disk. I configured it to run on a raw non-formatted partition. That gives 40-50% throughput boost for my experimental workload, presumably because we avoid the OS overheads of transforming data to and from a file format. I am also using the O_DIRECT flag to bypass the OS cache thereby ensuring that all IOs hit disk. I am running Ubuntu 13.10. The hard drive was originally a micron SSD.

Last week out of nowhere, my computer suddenly crashed. I wasn't even running an experiment at the time. When I tried to restart the BIOS couldn't find the boot loader. I thought it must be because the SSD got corrupted, so I replaced it. I re-installed everything, and started running experiments again. At some point my laptop ran out of battery, and when I reconnected it to electricity, the exact thing as before happened: the BIOS again couldn't find the bootloader.

This is a massive problem for me. I am not sure if the computer is messed up, or if it's my experiments that keep corrupting it the bootloader.

Comment: By *"non-formatted raw partition"* presumably that simply means that there is no filesystem defined for that partition.  If you have `open()`d the correct partition (e.g. **/dev/sda2**) and not the entire disk drive (i.e. **/dev/sda**) then the write (and read) operations should be restricted to that partition.  After all, this is exactly what the low-level filesystem code does.

Comment: Yes, this was my line of reasoning as well.. I just started doubting it the second time it happened. I have just reinstalled everything a third time. This time, however, I reverted to my old Micron SSD and made a firmware update from version O3TH to O4TH. This version offers two interesting fixes: "an issue where the system loses the SATA link which subsequently causes an issue where the system cannot detect a SSD that is connected to the system", and "an issue that causes the SSD to become corrupted when the system is powered off." Perhaps it had something to do with that.